# PHP function definition

Tags: php, function, definition

i made a php function countResponses that takes an array of feedback statements and shows how many times the statement occurred

```
$responses=array('Good','Good','OK','Bad','Good');
print "Number is ".countResponse('Good',$responses);
```

Heres the definition of countResponses but not sure if its correct

```
function countResponse($a,$e){
$countNumber=1;
foreach($a as $responses){
  if($responses = $u) {$count=$count++};
  };
return countResponses;
}
```

Any help please? Thanks

Comment: `if($responses = $u) {$count=$count++};` will always be true because you are assigning a variable and not forming a comparison. use `==` instead.

Comment: You have a LOT of syntax errors. Did you even test this?

Comment: im a novice and cannot test it right now. i'd greatly appreciate it if someone can make a correct version

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. Test it out and if you're still having problems, edit the question to ask a specific question regarding the problems you're having

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems with your parameters.

You call the function like `countResponse('Good',$responses)` with the expression first and the array second. Your function, however, is `function countResponse($a,$e)` with array first and expression second. Additionally, you are using `$u` instead of `$e` in the code. And you have semicolon issues, as seen in `.{$count=$count++};`. The icing on the cake is that you return the name of the function (kind of) with `return countResponses;`.

I don't believe you actually tested this code at all, but let's fix it:

```
function countResponse($a,$e)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach($a as $responses)
    {
        if($responses == $e)
        {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

As a note, there are other ways to search an array to get number of appearances of an element, but that's up to you to investigate. For the problem you have in front of you, that's beyond the scope of this question.

You can call your function as such:

```
countResponse($responses,'Good')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function countResponse($a, $e){
    $count = 0;
    foreach($a as $responses){
        if($responses === $e) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

call it like this

```
$responses=array('Good','Good','OK','Bad','Good');
print "Number is ".countResponse($responses, 'Good');
```